# Position Bootstrap button correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to position a Bootstrap styled dropdown button for use with a table. I can get it so the container rows butt up, but then there is a visual gap between the button and the edge of the table. I'm trying to shrink that gap (to maybe 3 px?).

I've messed with absolute and relative positioning, but for some reason my brain just isn't getting it.

I quick put together this fiddle to help shown what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/rbennett/emup7wpe/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    Trying to figure out how to correctly position a button for a table...
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="button-row">
      <button id="itemsButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Items<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="itemSelectorDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="other-row">
      <table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
      I have elements from a DatatTable table that sit right here<br />so I'm looking to position the "Items" button on the same line,<br />but aligned to the right.
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>abc</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>qrs</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone nudge me in the right direction on how to position the button so that it is right above the table (and not have a gap)?

Answer (score 0):

just change border-radius:0 in your button

```
#itemsButton
{border-radius:0;float:right;}
```

```css
.other-row {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
#itemsButton
{border-radius:0; float:right}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    Trying to figure out how to correclty position a button...
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="other-row">
    <div class="button-row">
      <button id="itemsButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Items<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="itemSelectorDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
  
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>abc</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>qrs</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your html just a tiny bit. I moved the button just above the table.
I also added 1 rule to move the button.

```css
.other-row {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

#itemsButton{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    Trying to figure out how to correclty position a button...
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="button-row">

      <ul id="itemSelectorDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="other-row">
    <button id="itemsButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Items<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
        We want to see the "Items" button here (aligned to the right)     
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>abc</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>qrs</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```